# PYTHONPATH exported multiple times when added to .zprofile

Tags: python, linux, zsh, pythonpath

I recently was trying to add a directory to PYTHONPATH using .zprofile and it worked, but it adds the directory over and over again so when I echo $PYTHONPATH it shows /Users/will/Python: over and over maybe 1000 times or so. This is what I have in my .zprofile so far.`# .zprofile/.bash_profile

#DIRS=(/Users/will/Python/**) # Store all the subdirectories in this variable
DIRS=(/Users/will/Python)
export PYTHONPATH=${(j<:>)DIRS}:$PYTHONPATH  # prepend those subdirectories to PYTHONPATH

` In need of help. :(

Answer (score 0):

@Shermanator98 : Put the directory into the path only the first time, not every time the file is sourced again. This is usually done by using a guard variable:

```
if (( ${+pythonpath_extended} == 0 ))
then
  export PYTHONPATH=....
  export pythonpath_extended=X # Any value will do
fi
```

Having said this, `~/.zprofile` is executed only for login shells. Since you said that your Pythonpath is extended over and over, it means that in your system, you have a deep nesting of ZSH login shells, which is absolutely strange and something I recommend you to investigate. Or do you have some script, which explicitly sources this file over and over?

Comment: There is no script that I know of that could be doing that. I just checked and it looks the like the nesting issue must have been just for that specific terminal instance. Closed terminal and opened a new window and the issue was resolved. Thank you so much for your help.